# It's hard to get a taxi "at this period"?

Tags: word-choice

Say it's 5:00 PM in a city, rush hour, hard to get a taxi. What do you say:

> "It's hard to get a taxi at **this period/this clock/this hour**"?

We can bypass it by saying "now". But what's the way to express it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would say "..at this time of day." or "...at this hour."

Comment: Also, just so you know, "this clock" can't ever be used to refer to the time in any situation.

Comment: I agree, "...at this time" or "...at this hour" would be most appropriate.